# Execute loop function for specific files from a directory

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I have a folder contains 10 files (in 5 categories depending on time of measurements is Sec) sorted by name as follow:

```
   measured_data_2Sec_1_.txt
   measured_data_2Sec_2_.txt

   measured_data_4Sec_1_.txt
   measured_data_4Sec_2_.txt
   .
   .
   .
   measured_data_10Sec_1_.txt
   measured_data_10Sec_2_.txt
```

I need to run a loop function as follow:

First import only files with *2Sec*:

```
measured_data_2Sec_1_.txt
measured_data_2Sec_2_.txt
```

and analysis data and save them, then return back to import only files with *4Sec*:

```
measured_data_4Sec_1_.txt
measured_data_4Sec_2_.txt
```

and so on....

I tried my code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import glob
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 files = glob.glob("input/*.txt")
 for f in files:
     intial_data = np.loadtxt(f)
 # Select Y-axis
     amp = intial_data[:,0]
 # Select X-axis
     volt = intial_data[:,1]

 # modify X-axis 
     amp_corr = amp*2
 # modify Y-axis 
     volt_corr = volt/0.2
     plt.plot(amp_corr ,volt_corr )
```

But this code run the loop for all of them.
My target is to run the loop for each category separately.

Comment: what's wrong with `glob.glob("input/*_2Sec_*.txt")` ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers - Yes, it's working good. 
If I need to repeat the loop for (_4Sec_) and so on.....
what should I do??

Comment: Can't you think of a solution by yourself (this is really really basic progarmming stuff)? Hint: you will need an outer loop, and an array with two strings which will be passed to `glob.glob()`.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers - Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. And please post the solution as an answer once you have the problem solved ;-)

Comment: Sure, I will do that